# How to identify a selected static UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've thought of a couple of approaches to use inside the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method:

- Create outlets and link the cells to them, then check which one was selected by comparing the reference
- Set and check a unique reuseIdentifier property on each cell
- Use the indexPath, because you know which cell is at which index since they're defined statically anyway

What is the best approach? Or perhaps there's another, better approach?

Comment: Definitely indexPath. The other methods don't seem right - that's not how a UITableView was designed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely indexpath is the best approach as many of the delegates of tableview works on indexpaths. You can easily get hold of the rows by keeping a track of indexpath. I guess you can also put to use the property of cell called 'selected' to check whether a cell state is selected or not. Hope this helps. Also make use of apple docs on tableviews.